# How to debug production setup for java?

Tags: remote-debugging, production-environment, production

I am currently working on a web-app. Basically deployed as .war file on production enviornment.  The server is tomcat7.
Since the code is written in java. There are ocassional log statements on server side.
If I am given an issue to resolve, I do not have a duplicate data-set / subset of data , as like production. So the problem that I face, is replicating the scenario , in case of testing.

Since this is production enviornment, attaching a remote debugger , would mean that the functionality would halt/ when I am stepping through break points, So I am not able to debug remotely.

so, currently, the only visiblity I have with regards to the behavior of the system is, The code base, and the log statements in code.

How Do you suggest I debug the server side code without restarting the application.

Any insight in this matter would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot attach a remote debugger in production there is no other way to debug your code other than the logs and matching the line number in your code.

1) You could ask for the sample scenarios which caused the issue and try to reproduce it in your development environment with debugger attached. 
2) You could fine tune the log level to DEBUG mode to catch more useful logs. 
3) Check various logs like application log, server log, access log, etc
3) You could ask for the test data which has caused the issue and try the same in dev environment.

Ideally you need a mock production environment with minimum mock data so that you could attach your debugger and step into the code.

Otherwise it would be time consuming and impossible to reproduce the production issues.